# what is the C# equivalent to struct.unpack("21", logfile.read(8))?

Tags: c#, python

I don't have much experience working directly with binary files ("I'm trying to teach myself right now) and I'm working with a python example. I know how to read in binary files in C# but I don't quite understand what is happening in this python bit:

```
 headerparts = struct.unpack("2l", logfile.read(8))
 headerlen = headerparts[1] - headerparts[0]
 header = struct.unpack(str(headerlen)+"l", logfile.read(headerlen*4))
```

I assume what is happening is that it is reading in 8 bytes and then using it to figure out the length of the header through...something, I'm not quite sure.

The Python documentation states this about struct.unpack:

**struct.unpack(fmt, string)**
Unpack the string (presumably packed by pack(fmt, ...)) according to the given format. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The string must contain exactly the amount of data required by the format (len(string) must equal calcsize(fmt)).

I don't quite understand what the "21" means. It implies it's a format, but I don't see a table describing what "21" is and I don't know if it means something else. Can someone explain what's going on here and/or show me the C# equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `21`, but `2l` meaning two `l`.

`l` means `long` (See [`struct` - Format characters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).)

Comment: Ok so this is doing what then? Returning me 4 long integers as a tuple? Then subtracting the first long from the second long to determine the header length?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, It return 2 integers, not 4.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, It seems like first int represent the length of the boy, and the second int represent the length of the all contents (both header, body)

Comment: Yes, it would appear so. This definitely helped understand  what was happening but I'm not sure it answered what I was looking for. However, this did lead me to  answer. Since I did say and/or c# example, I'll pick this as the answer and post my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it in C#:

```
// get bytes from file
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("parseMe.log");

// figure out the header length
var bodyLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileBytes, 0);
var headerLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileBytes, 4) - bodyLength;

// capture the header, which is an array of end index offsets
var header = new int[headerLength];

// grab the header out of the file
for (var index = 0; index < headerLength; ++index)
    header[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileBytes, 8 + index * 4);
```